# Reason of missing [Bind] attribute in Web API

Tags: c#, .net

Controller Scaffolding for MVC generates [Bind] attribute.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("InfoId
                    ,UserName,BranchId,BranchName,CustomerName")] Info info)
```

Where as Scaffolding for API do not generates that attribute.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Info>> PostVerificationInformation(Info info)
```

I'm looking for key differences between these two generated code w.r.t [Bind] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, when dealing with MVC action parameters you are commonly receiving either ViewModels or Business entities, and the [Bind] attribute is included to prevent overposting or mass assignment model binding attacks, this way only specified attributes are associated during model binding.

Conversely in WebAPI you are mostly receiving parameters that directly represent your Data Contracts so it is unlikely that you want to omit certain attributes for the binding process.